# How to get date many2one field option in odoo?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo

I have created some task at **calender.event** on different dates and customized code I will create one field for date which is from calender.event in customized  i need to get only before today I mean if I created any task or event  on 3,4,5,6,7,8th august 2015. and today is 6th august 2015 .Now I have to get only completed event like 3,4,5th august 2015 in that customized field.

Just describe how can i achieve it .

Answer (score 0):

```
def _check_dates(self):
   start = self.start_date or False
   end = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
   if start and end :
      if start < end:
         return False
return True

_constraints = [
(_check_dates, 'Error ! Start Date must be greater then Current Date', ['start_date'])
```

]

Hope this may help you.